# Como puedo ordenar de mayor a menor la nota media y mostrarla junto al nombre al que corresponde en java

Tags: java

El ejercicio dicta lo siguiente:
El archivo ‘alumnos_notas.txt’ contiene una lista de 10 alumnos y las notas que han obtenido en
cada asignatura. El número de asignaturas de cada alumno es variable. Implementa un programa
que muestre por pantalla la nota media de cada alumno junto a su nombre y apellido, ordenado
por nota media de mayor a menor.
Bien, tengo todo listo, menos la parte en la que debo de ordenar, he pensado en usar un Arrays.sort pero no caigo como.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio2B {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        String nombre,apellido,linea;
        double media,suma;
        
        try
        {
            File fichero = new File("./Documentos/alumnos_notas.txt");
            Scanner lector = new Scanner(fichero);
            do
            {
                media = 0;
                suma = 0;
                linea = lector.nextLine();
                String parte[] = linea.split(" ");
                nombre = parte[0];
                apellido = parte[1];
                
                
                for (int i = 2; i < parte.length; i++) 
                {
                    
                    int numero = Integer.valueOf(parte[i]); 
                    
                    suma = suma + numero;
                    
                }
                media = suma / (parte.length - 2);
                
                System.out.println("Nombre: "+nombre + "\nApellido: "+apellido + "\nNota media: "+media+"\n");
                
            }
            while(lector.hasNextLine());
            lector.close();
            
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("ERROR. La ruta no existe");
        }
    }
}
```

El contenido del archivo luce asi:

```
Joanna Rogers 10 0 8 6 2 9
Michele Poole 5 9 8 5 4 9 8 2
Toni Harper 10 10 3 4 10
Troy Walters 5 10 1 4 10 10 9 2 3 6
Patrick Santos 5 4 9 8
Gabriel Moreno 6 4 4 4
Malcolm Lindsey 0 3 5 9 10 9 2
Gilbert Santiago 6 7 9 3 5 0
Ron Garza 7 8 5 3
Vivian Chambers 8 2 6 0
```

Comment: ¿cómo luce el archivo? ¿Podrías adjuntarlo para poder reproducir mejor tu problema?

Comment: Acabe de añadirlo

Comment: Otra pregunta, para ver cómo puedo ayudarte sin complicarte con conceptos que tal vez no conoces. ¿Manejas clases? No te sería más fácil crear un objeto alumno, y luego ordenar un array de objetos alumnos. Pregunto porque no se si al nivel que vas has visto estos conceptos.

Comment: La idea seria hacerlo sin clases, con clases tengo ya uno que me funciona. Pero espicificamente han dicho que se haga con Arrays.sort

Comment: Dado que es un ejercicio, conviene que aclares qué cosas te piden y qué limitaciones tienes. Aquí lo propio sería crear un `TreeMap`, el cual irá ordenando los elementos y llenarlo dentro del `do ... while`. Independientemente de los límites que tengas, debes tener claro que la `media` tendría que ser numérico, porque si lo guardas como cadena, no obtendrás el orden deseado, pues considerará que `"100"` es inferior a `"3"` por ejemplo.

Comment: Digas lo que digas, si tienes que usar `Arrays.sort`, mínimo debes tener una clase `Alumno`, porque puede fácilmente ordenar las notas con `Arrays.sort`, pero dado que tienes los nombres por separados no sabrás qué nota corresponderá con qué alumno. Porque lo otro es hacer un extraño array de maps que lo veo mucho más sucio. Checa [este ejemplo](https://onlinegdb.com/oDze__gvc) con una clase alumno y `Arrays.sort` y muy buena suerte.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez es cierto que sería mejor una clase, pero ten en cuenta que es un ejercicio, y a veces el profesor pone limitaciones. Saber a quién corresponden las notas no es ningún problema, cada grupo de notas está en una línea y cada línea corresponde a un alumno, por tanto, no hay ningún problema para diferenciar.

Comment: @A.Cedano no veo cómo saber cómo corresponder las notas con los nombres con `Arrays.sort`. ¿Me podrías dar una pista que no use una clase ni un array de  maps o algo así? Una vez ordenado un arreglo de promedios (suponiendo se tenga un arreglo de promedios), no hay manera de matchearlos con los nombres. Imagina que dos promedios sean iguales, ¿Quien es quien? Recuerda que si no usas una clase, o algún tipo de collection, no hay manera de agrupar los datos.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Si lees mi comentario más arriba verás lo que he dicho a OP sobre el asunto: usando un `TreeMap` por ejemplo tendría los valores ordenados sin necesidad de `Arrays.sort()`. Pero es OP quien debe decir qué limitaciones le imponen sobre las clases (de Java o personalizadas) que puede usar o no. Además hay otro aspecto mucho más serio y que no explica: el criterio a seguir para agrupar las notas en cada fila. Si TODAS las personas tienen sólo una palabra para el nombre y otra para el apellido (algo poco probable e irreal) puede crear un sub-array a partir del segundo índice ...

Comment: ... de lo contrario tendrá que usar algo así con un REGEX que detecte el primer valor numérico y recoger todos los valores a partir de ahí o bien intentar una converión a número, capturando las excepciones. No veo otra forma de ir encontrando cada valor de las `notas`. Es un dato fundamental en este código del cual OP no nos dice nada tampoco. Creo que la pregunta está demasiado en el aire y que mientras no se aclaren ninguno de esos aspectos, poco podremos ayudar.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si lees mi comentario me refería especificamente a usando `Arrays.sort`. De cualquier manera muchas gracias por la aclaración. Hay varias colecciones que son viables para el problema, pero desafortunadamente no son compatibles con  `Arrays.sort`. Esperemos que el OP se aclare.